# How to groupby multiple columns and aggregate data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns (`words, start time, stop time, speaker`):

- I want to combine all values in the `word` column while the values in the `data` column do not change OR the values in the column `meta_data` do not change.
- In addition, I want to keep the `start` value for the first word and the `stop` value for the last word in the combination.

I currently have:

```
      word  start  stop     data    meta_data  
0      but   2.72  2.85        2      9
1   that's   2.85  3.09        2      9
2  alright   3.09  3.47        2      1
3    we'll   8.43  8.69        1      4
4     have   8.69  8.97        1      4
5       to   8.97  9.07        1      4
6     okay   9.19 10.01        2      2
7     sure  10.02 11.01        2      1
8    what?  11.02 12.00        1      4
```

However, I would like to turn this into:

```
       word       start  start  data  meta_data
0  but that's      2.72   3.09     2    9
1  alright         3.09   3.47     2    1
2  we'll have to   8.43   9.07     1    4
3  okay            9.19  10.01     2    2
4  sure            10.02 11.01     2    1
5  what?           11.02 12.00     1    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This need to create a help key , then we do `shift` + `cumsum` create the groupkey based on that

```
df['Key']=df[['data','meta_data']].apply(tuple,1)
d={'word':' '.join,'start':'min','stop':'max','data':'first','meta_data':'first'}
df.groupby(df.Key.ne(df.Key.shift()).cumsum()).agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[171]: 
            word  start   stop  data  meta_data
0     but that's   2.72   3.09     2          9
1        alright   3.09   3.47     2          1
2  we'll have to   8.43   9.07     1          4
3           okay   9.19  10.01     2          2
4           sure  10.02  11.01     2          1
5          what?  11.02  12.00     1          4
```

Answer (score 2):

**doing some math here** + [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

```
s=df['data']+df['meta_data']
groups=s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
new_df=( df.groupby(groups)
           .agg({'word':' '.join,'start':'min',
                 'stop':'max','data':'first',
                 'meta_data':'first'}) )
print(new_df)

            word  start   stop  data  meta_data
1     but that's   2.72   3.09     2          9
2        alright   3.09   3.47     2          1
3  we'll have to   8.43   9.07     1          4
4           okay   9.19  10.01     2          2
5           sure  10.02  11.01     2          1
6          what?  11.02  12.00     1          4
```

---

if you think that the sum can correspond in two different and consecutive groups you can use a somewhat more complex function with decimals

```
p=(df['data']+0.1723).pow(df['meta_data']+2.017)
groups=p.ne(p.shift()).cumsum()
```